# On iOS, how can smooth animation be achieved?

Tags: ios, animation, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

Is it true that for Angry Birds or Cut the Rope, they draw the whole frame of the whole screen first (the whole view), and then paint the whole frame onto the screen, making the animation smooth?

That's because if we animate a metal ball, of size 20 x 20 pixel, and if we erase the ball first, and then draw the ball at a new location, then there might be some flickering very subtle but noticeable.

The same might be if it is animated by `drawRect`, which will erase the whole screen, and then draw everything in their new locations, which might have even more flicker than above?

Going back to the drawing whole frame method: if a ball was at coordinate (100,100), and now the ball is painted on top of the whole screenshot (with the new background exposed), at coordinate (103, 100), then it is very unnoticeable for the changes. (no disappearing and then reappearing happening at all).

How can smooth animation be achieved that looks like Angry Birds or Cut the Rope game?

Comment: Some hints: [display-link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html), [view-buffer vs. render-buffer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They make use of OpenGL, which is *a lot* faster than any of the Quartz methods (ie. drawRect) since it makes use of the GPU instead of the CPU for rendering. Using Quartz can be hundreds or thousands of times slower depending on what you are doing exactly.

If you do not want to resort to OpenGL. You can put the object inside a UIView and then animate it. As long as the contents of the view is static, this is plenty fast for most applications. For example, making the background a view, and the metal ball a view, you can move that view around and achieve very smooth animations without problems.

Comment: so if using OpenGL ES or cocos2D, then if the ball is erased first, and then redrawn, it will still be smooth because it happens so quickly?  Could painting the whole new screen on top of the old screen be even more smooth? (no erasing of anything, just painting on top)

Comment: With OpenGL (or Cocos2D, which uses OpenGL behind the scenes), you generally clear the entire screen and redraw everything every single frame. This is plenty fast even on the iPhone.

Comment: @動靜能量 - The scene isn't being fully redrawn, for already-drawn elements the GPU merely has to composite elements on top of one another. This is a blazingly fast operation, as evidenced by smooth scrolling in table views, etc. which all are animated by compositing various UI elements on the GPU every 60th of a second. No flicker is visible in any of that, even on the original iPhone.

Comment: I can run 60FPS full screen animations on a modern iPhone with no problems. Not every problem needs to be solved directly in OpenGL, 3D ones yes, but not 2D problems as CoreGraphics works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use CALayers. They are more lightweight than views.

Comment: Actually, on iOS a UIView is a super thin layer on top of a CALayer. In terms of draw-speed you hardly ever find a difference.

Comment: Was under the impression that all the event handling added some weight to it as well as frame resizing and subview layout.

Comment: Use of CALayer is the right approach, you should not write code that extends UIView and then draws the entire screen over and over. There is no way that kind of approach will be fast. But, the graphics card can cache small images held in CALayers just as fast as OpenGL, because OpenGL is actually being used under the covers. You just need to program it right and reuse CALayer objects as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If an app uses OpenGL, the answer is yes, it does its rendering **before** the frame buffer is presented to the screen.  I think the other ways to draw to the screen use the same technique of drawing to an off-screen buffer before transferring the completed image to the screen, but I'm not so sure about that.